# Continuous Random Variable Introduction Question

Tags: probability

> A random variable X is normally distributed with a mean of 30 and a
>   standard deviation of 4.5. Find: P(X<36)

So far in my notes, I have said that 
$$1 - P(X>36)$$ $$ =1 -\frac{\ 30-36}{\ 4.5}$$ $$ = 1-1\frac{\ 1}{\ 3}$$ $$- \frac{\ 1}{\ 3}$$

I don't really understand the next part: $$ P (Z < \frac{\ 30-36}{\ 4.5}) = P(Z<1) $$ $$ = 1 - P(Z>1) $$
$$= 1-0.1587 = 0.8423$$ I don't understand how $P(Z< 1$) is equal to 0.158 or the relevance of this number. Is the answer not $- \frac{\ 1}{\ 3}$?

Comment: Can a probability be $-\frac13$?

Comment: $P(Z \lt -1) = P(Z \gt 1) \approx 0.1587$ for a standard normal distribution, but $\frac{30-36}{4.5}\not = 1$ or $-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called $standard$ Normal random variable, which is defined as $Z =\frac{X -\mu}{\sigma}$. Hence, since you know $\mu$ and $\sigma = 4.5 \ P(X <36) = P(X - 30<6) = P(\frac{X-30}{4.5} <\frac{6}{4.5}) = P(Z<\frac{4}{3})$, which you can find in thetable of the cdf for the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Your notes do not make much sense.

If a random variable $X$ is normally distributed with a mean of $30$ and a standard deviation of $4.5$ then $P(X\lt 36) = P\left(Z \lt \dfrac{36-30}{4.5}\right) = P\left(Z \lt \dfrac{4}{3}\right)$ where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution, i.e. with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

$P\left(Z \lt \dfrac{4}{3}\right) = \Phi(1.333\ldots) \approx  0.9087888$ which should be the answer to your question.

Comment: @Alex - thank you - edited to remove $^{-1}$